# Struts 2 Annotation Based Application Not Working

Tags: java, jsp, configuration, struts2, annotations

I'm following "Struts 2 in Action" book and under the first chapter of that book, there is a sample basic application to be developed. I tried to follow it and the action class is not calling properly. But I can view the success result JSP page. When I use the debug mode and try to debug the execute method of the action class, it is not calling. I'm using `struts-2.3.15.1` libraries to develop this application.

My Action class is below :

```
package manning.chapterTwo;

import org.apache.struts2.config.Result;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;



@Result(name="SUCCESS", value="/chapterTwo/HelloWorld.jsp" )
public class AnnotatedHelloWorldAction extends ActionSupport{


private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private static final String GREETING = "Hello ";


public String execute()  {

    setCustomGreeting( GREETING + getName() );

    return "SUCCESS";
}

private String name;


public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

private String customGreeting;

public String getCustomGreeting()
{
    return customGreeting;
}

public void setCustomGreeting( String customGreeting ){
    this.customGreeting = customGreeting;
}
}
```

JSP Page to get the Input looks like below (`NameCollector.jsp`) :

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<html>

<head>
<title>Name Collector</title>
</head>

<body>
    <hr>
    <h4>Enter your name so that we can customize a greeting just for you!</h4>  
    <s:form action="annotatedHelloWorld">
    <s:textfield name="name" label="Your name"/>
    <s:submit/>
    </s:form>
    <hr>
</body>

    </html>
```

Output JSP :

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<html>
<head>
<title>HelloWorld</title>
</head>

<body>

  <hr>
    <h3>Custom Greeting Page</h3>      
    <h4><s:property value="customGreeting"/></h4>
  <hr>
</body>
   </html>
```

`web.xml` file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>Struts2HelloWorldXML</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
    <param-name>actionPackages</param-name>
    <param-value>manning</param-value>
    </init-param>
   </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

How to resolve it?

Comment: Is there any exception? Could you please share the server log..

Comment: It would be a little bit usefull if you post a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) It is not easy to read that all...

Answer (score 0):

You should add an action annotation to the action class or method

```
@ParentPackage("chapterTwo");
@Action(value="HelloWorld", results=@Result(name="SUCCESS", value="/chapterTwo/HelloWorld.jsp" ))
public class AnnotatedHelloWorldAction extends ActionSupport {
```

Supposed the author either using conventions to map your action or added the action annotation in the errata. Also added the parent package annotation to which the action belongs to. And don't forget to add [struts2-convention-plugin](/questions/tagged/struts2-convention-plugin) to the library set, because it's missed in the examples.

Comment: I have added the struts2-convention- plugin as well. The modification that Roman told is not working

Comment: It doesn't throw any error. But the execute method of the action class is not calling in the debug mode as well as the result is also not showing properly.

import org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation.Action;
import org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation.ParentPackage;
import org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation.Result;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;


@ParentPackage("chapterTwo")
@Action(value="/HelloWorld", results=@Result(name="SUCCESS", location="/chapterTwo/HelloWorld.jsp" ))

Comment: How did you check it?

Comment: I'm using eclipse as the ide and I have using the tomcat as the server with eclipse. I start the tomcat in debug mode from the eclipse and I checked it using the browser.